# How to repeat textbox on every page of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have one tablix on my report and I placed one textbox on the tablix this textbox works as a watermark for the report and it's working fine but I have to repeat this textbox on every page of the report but it is only displayed on the first page of the report. There is one RepeatWith property mentioned in many answers posted related to this type of question I have also tried this but it's not working for me That's how I set this property in my report. Textbox -- >properties ->other ->repeat with Tablix ( you should let tablix repeat) I have attached a screenshot of how my reports look like.[image]

Can anyone please help me why this is not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Does the watermark need to be behind the tablix? I was just thinking if you added a row above or below in the tablix and put it in there it would then repeat, albeit in a different position.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).